# O que são Exceptions e como devo cria-las e oganiza-las no PHP

Tags: php, exceção

Estou criando um sistema MVC e quero implementar *Exceptions* no meu sistema. Só que particularmente nunca utilizei. Então queria saber como devem ser aplicadas as Exceptions, já que eu vi aqui no StackOverflow em Português alguém falando (não lembro se em resposta ou comentário) que a maioria das pessoas não sabem como utilizar as *Exceptions* corretamente. Então eu me vi nesse grupo de pessoas que não sabe utilizar *Exceptions*, ou pelo menos nunca dei muita importância para elas, mas agora vi uma real necessidade de utiliza-las.

Como estou desenvolvendo [um código que será a base para vários projetos](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/Base) meus futuramente, tanto academicamente como mesmo profissionalmente, preciso padroniza-lo e desenvolve-lo de forma que realmente torne o desenvolvimento de algum projeto algo mais "simples" ou focado e que facilite e não dificulte.

As *Exceptions* entram na história para ajudar na parte de *debug*, quero que o *framework* me de o rastro do erro, de onde começou até onde parou. Preciso saber os motivos dos erros e também que eles me indiquem como corrigi-los. E como sou novo na programação orientada a objetos é a primeira vez que me vejo criando *Exceptions* e não tratando-as. Mas chega de história, vamos ao código.

[Já criei uma `Exception`, código](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/Base/blob/master/base/core/exception/systemexception.class.php):

```
<?php
namespace Core\Exception;
use \Exception;

class SystemException extends Exception {
   function __construct($code, $args = array(), Exception $previous = NULL ) {
      $language = (require BASE . 'language' . DS . LANG . DS . 'exceptions.php');
      $format = $language[$code];

      $message = vsprintf($format, $args);
      parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
   }
   // personaliza a apresentação do objeto como string
   // public function __toString() {
   //    return __CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
   // }
}
```

Então a minha ideia era criar essa `SystemException` para realizar logs dos erros e todas as demais serem estendidas dela, ou algo parecido. (Até o momento não sei se isso vai funcionar). Note que eu também modifiquei o tipo de construtor, na verdade não sei se isso é uma boa prática, a ideia é facilitar a tradução dos erros. Mas não sei se deveria deixar isso para o "sistema" que for desenvolvido em vez de dar essa responsabilidade para o *framework*.

[E aqui uma forma onde estou lançando a exceção](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/Base/blob/master/base/core/route.class.php#L32):

```
protected function register($params){
   if (empty($params['controller']))
      throw new SystemException(Exceptions::E_INVALIDPARAMETERVALUE, ['NULL', '$params[controller]']);
   if (empty($params['action']))
      throw new SystemException(Exceptions::E_INVALIDPARAMETERVALUE, ['NULL', '$params[action]']);
   if (empty($params['lang'])){
      $params['lang'] = (empty($_COOKIE['language']) ? LANG : $_COOKIE['language']);
      throw new SystemException(Exceptions::E_INVALIDPARAMETERVALUE, ['NULL', '$params[controller]']);
   }

}
```

Quando estou lançando uma exceção estou apenas criando-a informando um código, que busca as mensagem em um arquivo de idiomas e passo como parâmetros em um *array* dados utilizados na mensagem.

Então queria saber se eu entendi o conceito e estou aplicando de forma correta as exceções?

Então tem alguns pontos/questões sobre a criação e conceito de *Exceptions*:

- Como padronizar as exceções?
- Como registrar *logs* das exceções lançadas, de forma automática?
- Qual a aplicação do [parâmetro `previous` na Exceção do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.extending.php)?
- Quais as boas práticas e más práticas sobre as *Exceptions*?

Obs.: A automaticidade do registros de *logs* seria a ideia de uma classe "pai" registrar *logs* toda vez que uma exceção for lançada a partir de uma classe que herda dela.

Comment: Tem gente que falou que o pessoal não sabe usar `Exceptions` corretamente? QUem será :P Não sei se teria uma resposta específica para o PHP, mas já existe muita coisa sobre o assunto na tag: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o e principalmente nas minhas respostas na tag: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+%5Bexception%5D Eu falo sobre tudo o que está perguntado, embora algumas coisas são para outras linguagens. Não sei se dá para colocar algo novo além do que já postei. É um recurso quase idêntico em todas linguagens. O que será que posso escrever?

Comment: @bigown vou dar uma olhada no conteúdo qualquer se eu ver que já respondeu tudo eu marco como duplicada ou deleto sei lá, senão te aviso...

Comment: @bigown tem muita coisa especifica em C#, eu queria especificamente para PHP, vou colocar uma `Exception` que já criei na pergunta e talvez dar uma reformulada nela pra não ficar tão ampla.

Comment: @bigown dei uma repaginada na pergunta... Não sei se melhorou muito... :P

Comment: Pode ter algumas coisas específicas aí que eu não vou arriscar.

Answer (score 3):

Posso te ajudar quanto a pergunta: *Como eu poderia padronizar minhas exceções e registrar logs das exceções lançadas de forma automática?*

Se entendi bem, você gostaria de lançar um log quando a exceção lançada fosse proveniente da instancia de `SystemException`.

Creio que o a função `set_exception_handler` pode te ajudar nesse caso. Veja:

```
set_exception_handler(function($exception)
{
      if ($exception instanceof SystemException) {
          file_put_contents('log.txt', (string)$exception, FILE_APPEND);
      }

     throw $e; // Outras exceções são tratadas de maneira padrão
});
```

No caso do seu código do método `Core\Route::register`, creio que ficou muito genérico utilizar a exceção `SystemException`.

Creio que uma abordagem mais elegante seria criar uma outra classe de exceções, que herde `SystemException`, para se referir somente às exceções que podem ocorrer no `Route`,

```
class RouteException extends SystemException
{}
```

Outro fato é que, pelo fato de se tratar também de tratamento dos argumentos, eu utilizaria exceções como `UnexpectedValueException` ou `InvalidArgumentException`. Se for o caso, você poderia também criar uma exceção herdeira de `SystemException` (que você quer usar para log) que fosse específica para informar a invalidade de argumentos.

Digo isso, porque o PHP trata as  duas expressões como `TRUE`, por conta da herança:

```
$e = new SystemException;

$re = new RouteException;

$e = instanceof SystemException; // True

$re instanceof RouteException; // True
```

Comment: Vou melhorar as informações da pergunta

Comment: Beleza Wallace, é nesse sentido mesmo. A intenção realmente é criar outras `Exceptions` como o exemplo que você deu `RouteException`.

Comment: A ideia de tratar `exceptions`, nada mais é do que você responder a cada saída de erro numérico, uma mensagem de resposta que seja interessante para o usuário. Eu sinceramente não vejo a necessidade disso, já que um framework já tem isso implementado internamente, basta usar algum pacote de tradução.

Comment: E se o cara não usa framework? Ele vai ter que fazer na mão :)

Answer (score 2):

Aqui tem um exemplo de boas práticas para tratamento de **exceptions**, pois além de criar uma componentização e documentar seu sistema, permite que ninguém abaixo destrua seu funcionamento:

```
namespace SuaClasse\Component {

    interface Exception
    {}

    class UnexpectedValueException 
          extends \UnexpectedValueException 
          implements Exception
    {}

    class ReportingExpection
    {
        public static function doSomething()
        {
           try {
                if ($somethingExceptionalHappens) {
                    throw new UnexpectedValueException('mensagem da exceção');
                }

           } catch (UnexpectedValueException $e) {
              error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, "/var/tmp/errors.log");
           } 
        }
    }

}
```

Agora que já tem seu componente, é só usá-lo:

```
SuaClasse\Component\ReportingExpection::doSomething();
```

Comment: Eu vi o código, mas poderia explicar melhor o que ele faz e porque assim é um boa prática?

Comment: Olha esse artigo explica detalhadamente: http://ralphschindler.com/2010/09/15/exception-best-practices-in-php-5-3

Comment: O Zend Framework 2.0 segue essa linha.