# O que são Exceptions?

Tags: exceção, independente-de-linguagem

A pouco tempo fiz essa pergunta [O que são Exceptions e como devo cria-las e oganiza-las no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84234/o-que-s%C3%A3o-exceptions-e-como-devo-cria-las-e-oganiza-las-no-php), mas não tive uma resposta que abordasse de forma satisfatória os pontos levantados. Então estou recorrendo uma abordagem mais conceitual sobre *Exception*.

Qual o conceito de *Exception*? Qual seu propósito independente de linguagem? Quais as principais diferenças (se houver) das *Exceptions* entre as linguagens atuais?

Comment: Básicamento é uma saída do sistema para informar ao programador/usúario que não há como seguir com a fila de processamento daquela solicitação

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Concordo com o que tem na resposta do Eduardo Binotto. É um mecanismo que sinaliza um evento excepcional. AchoAchava que todo mundo concordava com isto. Mas tem umas pessoas que eu acho que deveriam estar em camisa de força que não pensam assim :D

Aí vem os detalhes e as discordâncias começam aparecer. Na [resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88856/101) tem um exemplo que pra mim não é uma exceção (e parece que ele concorda conceitualmente comigo, talvez não na hora de fazer). É um abuso do mecanismo porque ele não "ocorre quando acontece algo fora da regra comum". Dado inválido é regra comum. Faz parte do domínio ter um dado inválido. Não é uma situação excepcional.

Definir o que é excepcional ou não, é uma tarefa complicada e depende de muita experiência, eu ainda estou engatinhando nisto (pode ver no meu perfil e redes qual é a minha experiência, e sim estou engatinhando, você não?). Modelar é muito difícil e exceções ou outros mecanismos fazem parte do modelo, estabelece contratos.

E a coisa fica pior porque há casos em que o modelo diz que algo não é excepcional, mas por otimização (não de performance, mas para facilitar a escrita de um código) opta-se por usar uma exceção mesmo que a situação não seja excepcional. Muitas vezes acaba sendo necessário por não ter um mecanismo melhor.

A regra geral é não controlar o fluxo do programa com exceções, mas pode haver casos que isto seja vantajoso.

Eu considero o [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) um dos melhores exemplos quando uma comunicação de dado inválido não deve ser feita com exceção.

E nem falei do fato que [exceções são lentas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/101).

Quando você lança exceções em excesso o código consumidor do seu é obrigado fazer o que não deve. A pior exceção é a espúria (que seja apenas ruído [leia mais nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101)).

Então por muitas vezes é melhor tratar o dado inválido, a condição anormal ou até mesmo em alguns casos a falha com [algo não excepcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

O mecanismo em si funciona como um *super goto*. Em qualquer linguagem. O lançamento da exceção (`throw` ou outra palavra) é um um *goto*  para algum lugar não defino previamente. O `catch` é o *label* desse *goto* com o agravante que só no momento da execução é que se saberá onde ele está no fluxo geral. Ele está em outra rotina. Isso pode criar problemas de fluxo, tem que tomar cuidados específicos porque o método pode ser encerrado sem ação do seu próprio código.

Geralmente as pessoas criticam recursos muito menos perigosos, que tem muito menos potencial de risco. Muitas vezes adotam o mecanismo para deixar o código menor em certas situações. O que eu acho estranho é que outras coisas mais implícitas são criticadas pelas mesmas pessoas que defendem a exceção. E mais, é comum muitas vezes ela ser usada de forma que não deixa o código mais curto.

Há um mito que dizem que obriga o código tratar a exceção, o que vemos na prática que não é verdade, nem mesmo com exceções checadas. O que obriga é você ter uma informação completamente inválida, para o compilador mesmo, e aí você tem que tratar para usar o valor válido para compilar, e isto se faz com código de erro (veja o último *link*).

Então quem gosta do mecanismo começa usar sem pensar no modelo, sem estabelecer se faz parte da regra ou não.

Agrava a situação porque a exceção costuma ser usada para propósitos diferentes na maioria das linguagens, mais ainda nas linguagens dinâmicas. A exceção é usada para gerar erros de programação. Claro, não deixa de ser uma situação excepcional, embora deveria ter um mecanismo diferente, este é um caso claramente excepcional e seu uso é justo. O errado é tentar tratar isso no código, só deve alertar para o problema para o programador consertar o erro.

Em geral exceções devem ser usadas quando não importa muito o tratamento específico. Algumas linguagens criaram a cultura delas serem usadas para passar mensagens para o código consumidor, o que conceitualmente deveria ser algo não excepcional.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ainda vai melhorar? :P

Comment: @KaduAmaral provavelmente, só ñ lembro o q eu ia melhorar, esqueci dela. Tem bastante coisa pra falar sobre isto, preciso me recompor :) Vou deixar aberto aqui e conforme for lembrando eu vou mudando.

Comment: Legal, assim que terminar a parte de rotas do meu framework vou começar a me dedicar as exceptions.

Answer (score 8):

Exceção significa algo que não é comum, que não faz parte das regras. A exceção ocorre quando acontece algo fora da regra comum, um fato inédito, que não era feito ou conhecido antes, e foi aberta uma exceção.

O tratamento de exceção, na ciência da computação, é o mecanismo responsável pelo tratamento da ocorrência de condições que alteram o fluxo normal da execução de programas de computadores. Para condições consideradas parte do fluxo normal de execução, ver os conceitos de sinal e evento.

Exceção são usadas para fazer tratamentos em seu código, ou seja, podemos fazer um controle de exceção em determinada parte de um código fonte para saber qual foi o erro que levou ao problema(Que causou uma exceção).

Exemplo, se em um determinado trecho do seu código você quer validar se ocorreu um determinado tipo de erro, pode ser uma classe nula, o famoso `NullPointerException` do java, assim você pode tratar seu erro instanciando o objeto que estava nulo.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

     try  {

        String[] array = new String[]{"erro", "de", "indice"};
        System.out.println(array[3]);

      } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
         System.out.println("Exceção detectada");
      }

  }
```