# É possivel declarar que em uma função lança um exceção com PHP?

Tags: php, exceção, throw

Com um pequeno exemplo:

```
public function calcularMedia($valor){
    if($valor < 0){
        //LANÇAR EXCEÇÃO
    }
    else if($valor > 6){
        return "Passou";
    }else{
        return "Recuperação";
    }
}
```

Lembrando essa função é chamada por outra, que tem um bloco `try` e um `catch` então gostaria de saber se é possível lançar uma exceção em minha função para calcular média caso o valor informado seja menos que *0*.

Comment: Você quer lançar uma exceção ou declarar que a função pode lançar uma exceção? São duas coisas completamente diferentes. Se quer lançar, tem alguma dúvida específica? Afinal, é só lançar.

Comment: Boa pergunta @Maniero, você pode fazer um resposta com as 2 coisas se possível eu não sei qual a diferença? A minha dúvida é se ali onde tem "LANÇAR EXCEÇÃO", eu possa retornar um `throws Exception`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não pode declarar explicitamente (*checked exception*) que uma função pode lançar uma exceção porque PHP não é Java, a única linguagem que permite isso, e não deu certo.

Você pode lançar uma exceção da forma mais simples possível, mas se fizer isso estará programando como se fosse Java, então se quer programar em Java, vá para Java.

Tecnicamente pode fazer isto:

```
public function calcularMedia($valor) {
    if ($valor < 0) throw new ValorNegativoException();
    return $valor > 6 ? "Passou" : "Recuperação";
}
```

Você teria que [criar uma exceção própria para isso](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php). Se não for fazer certo então pra que usar esse mecanismo?

Algumas pessoas preferirão fazer isto, mas é [abuso do mecanismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101):

```
public function calcularMedia($valor) {
    if ($valor < 0) throw new Exception("Valor Negativo");
    return $valor > 6 ? "Passou" : "Recuperação";
}
```

Pode pelo menos fazer um meio termo, em alguns casos é ok:

```
public function calcularMedia($valor) {
    if ($valor < 0) throw new InvalidArgumentException("Valor Negativo");
    return $valor > 6 ? "Passou" : "Recuperação";
}
```

Mas PHP pode ser só:

```
public function calcularMedia($valor) {
    if ($valor < 0) return false;
    return $valor > 6 ? "Passou" : "Recuperação";
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Exception/ArgumentError.php).

Aí você testa se veio `false` e não precisa de um `try-catch`, você só aceita um valor se ele for diferente de `false`. è mais correto porque você espera que isso aconteça, não é uma situação excepcional.

Se não entender muito profundamente como usar exceção corretamente é melhor não usar, até porque PHP foi criada toda sem pensar nisso. É verdade que ultimamente estão incentivando mais o seu uso, o que faz a linguagem perder identidade e começa virar Java. Java é um Java bem melhor que PHP. PHP é um PHP fenomenal e exceção deve ser algo excepcional no código. Até Java tem se afastado de exceção.

Pode ler mais em:

- [O que são Exceptions?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88831/101)
- [Exceção não é controle de fluxo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101)
- [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101)

Comment: _"Java, a única linguagem que permite isso, e não deu certo" [citation needed]_ pq não deu certo? Tem uns negacionistas por aí.

Comment: https://testing.googleblog.com/2009/09/checked-exceptions-i-love-you-but-you.html e https://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html e https://blog.overops.com/ignore-checked-exceptions-all-the-cool-devs-are-doing-it-based-on-600000-java-projects/ e https://web.archive.org/web/20180215103021/http://www.mindview.net/Etc/Discussions/CheckedExceptions e http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2012/02/checked-exceptions-might-have-their.html e https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05254/index.html e https://cafe.elharo.com/programming/bruce-eckel-is-wrong/ (ele tá errado e o Bruce Eckel tá certo).