# O que escrever em uma classe de exceção (Exception)?

Tags: exceção, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação

Estava olhando essa pergunta no Stack Overflow <sup>en</sup> [How can I write custom Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070590/how-can-i-write-custom-exceptions) e a resposta mais bem votada (e aceita) foi:

```
public class MyNewException extends RuntimeException {

    public MyNewException(){
        super();
    }

    public MyNewException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Ou seja, ele apenas declarou uma classe e chamou os construtores da classe pai.

Qual o propósito disso? Pelo meu (pouco) entendimento a criação de novas "*exceptions*" são basicamente para identifica-las, estou certo?

Já vi um código semelhante a este em PHP:

```
try{
   // Algum Código
} catch(UmaException $e) {
   // Faz alguma coisa
} catch(OutraException $e) {
   // Faz outra coisa
}
```

Então a criação das diversas *exceptions* são para identificá-las e preparar uma saída de acordo com o tipo de exceção? A mensagem passada como parâmetro já não faria esse trabalho?

Comment: **Obs.:** Se a resposta for sim, irei remover a pergunta... :v

Comment: Identificar é uma das razões, outra poderia ser passar parâmetros identificando exatamente o que aconteceu, onde, quais os objetos envolvidos, etc. Mas se nada disso for necessário, melhor reutilizar uma das classes prontas mesmo (opinião minha, não tome como fato).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na maior parte das vezes você vai criar exceções assim mesmo. Num primeiro momento parece esquisito, mas pense na semântica que quer passar.

Não é bem diferente você dizer que houve uma `Exception` e uma `BadFileFormat`? Mesmo que internamente estas classes não mudem nada, a segunda é bem mais específica e informativa. E [por ser mais específica pode ser capturada com maior granularidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101).

Evidentemente que é provável que a mensagem de texto que a exceção costuma ter também será personalizada. Muitas vezes mesmo que você passe algum texto quando vai lançar a exceção, o texto real é formado por este parâmetro e mais alguma coisa que já existe dentro da classe.

Tem que se pensar até que ponto quer ter essa granularidade. Ela é boa até certo ponto. Há casos que é melhor colocar este detalhamento dentro da própria exceção. Veja as [exceções de erros de banco de dados](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-8.0), não tem uma exceção para cada erro possível. O detalhamento está dentro da classe, possivelmente com propriedades que só esta exceção tem. Então há casos que há bem mais coisas que se escreve na exceção.

Eventualmente pode-se se escrever um método que ajude se recuperar da exceção, mas não vejo ninguém fazendo isto e acredito ser uma prática ruim. Minha intuição diz que sim, mas não tenho base para afirmar.

Mas o mais comum é adicionar propriedades específicas com informação relevante. Por exemplo, um erro de SQL pode ter um `ErrorCode` e `ErrorMessage` (esta é mais específica que a mensagem geral da exceção. Pense nas informações que você pode adicionar (que está disponível) e que o código que capturar a exceção pode usar de alguma forma útil, seja para decidir o que fazer, seja para apresentar uma informação mais direcionada ao usuário ou colocar no *log*.

Eu costumo dizer que [exceção nem sempre é o melhor mecanismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101), ainda que as linguagens e *frameworks* atuais incentivem muito ele e você acaba tendo que se adaptar a isto.

Tem uma [resposta minha que mostra quando deve se criar e lançar exceções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101), provavelmente ajude entender esta questão.

Outra [informação relevante antes de sair fazendo exceção para tudo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Haha, vou ter que tirar um final de semana com feriado emendado pra ler o que você diz sobre utilizar _exceptions_ nem sempre é o melhor mecanismo. :v ta detalhando bem, na verdade acho que vou ler minha pergunta de novo e depois ler a resposta novamente pra ver se entendi direito. rsrs

Comment: Na verdade já viu tudo que tema a *tag* `exceção` que eu respondi? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D Sou meio que um curador do assunto :) Este é o recurso mais mal usado da programação atualmente.

Comment: Haha as estatísticas não são bem assim, você tá manipulando a pesquisa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Ayes+%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D Zoeira, já reparei que você manja do assunto, [só não quis se aventurar no PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84234/o-que-s%c3%a3o-exceptions-e-como-devo-cria-las-e-oganiza-las-no-php). auehuaehue

Comment: Estatística tem pra todo gosto. Não coloquei nada para medir isto. Só listei o que eu postei. Eu acho que minhas respostas são mais canônicas, as outras são mais específicas. Mas não estou dizendo que tudo o que eu falo tem unanimidade, tem quem discorde de mim. Eu tentei dar o máximo de informação possível para mostrar meu ponto. Não sei se manjo, mas gosto. Eu acho o uso de exceção no PHP excepcionalmente ruim, inconsistente e não tenho muita experiência com ela, então evito um pouco. Mas pra falar a verdade eu não lembro de ter visto esta pergunta.

Comment: É verdade sobre as resposta, geralmente aborda o tema mais profundamente com bons argumentos. Quanto a não ter visto a pergunta, olha isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84234/o-que-s%C3%A3o-exceptions-e-como-devo-cria-las-e-oganiza-las-no-php#comment170718_84234 :v

Comment: É verdade, não me lembrava de nada dela :) De fato eu não entendo muito do mecanismo específico do PHP e fiquei com medo de escrever besteira.

Answer (score 2):

Correto, assim se em algum ponto do seu sistema, ou seja, em alguma parte do seu código você precisar levantar uma exceção, então levantaria uma exceção já conhecida por você.

Digamos que você queira validar se o usuário está logado em seu sistema, e que caso ele não esteja, você iria levantar uma exceção. então você iria fazer o seguinte:

```
public class UsuarioNaoLogado extends RuntimeException {

    public UsuarioNaoLogado (){
        super();
    }

    public UsuarioNaoLogado (String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

E para levantar uma exceção que o usuário não está logado faria assim:

```
 throw new UsuarioNaoLogado();
```

Desta forma em diversos pontos do seu código fonte você pode levantar uma exceção sinalizando que o usuário não esta logado usando a mesma `Exception` no caso `UsuarioNaoLogado()`.

Mas você pode também cria uma `Execption` para salvar mais informações por exemplo, quando determinada `Execption` você salvaria em um banco de dados a data que ocorreu o erro, então faria dentro da classe por exemplo.

Comment: Você é programador Java, né?

Comment: Também, na verdade trabalho também PHP, Delphi e Swift, entre outras. Porque ?

Comment: É que criar exceção para dado inválido muito Java. Tem quem goste, eu abomino e a cultura em outras linguagens não incentiva muito isto. É verdade que algumas linguagens foram contaminadas pela forma do Java de achar que tudo é situação excepcional. Ficou curioso? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101 Eu adoro falar sobre o assunto, se procurar no meu perfil pela *tag* específica, tem muita informação http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D

Comment: Li sua resposta que comentou achei muito interessante sua abordagem sobre o assunto, e concordo plenamente com o que você falou.